# Mysql results always returning NULL in SELECT ... FROM (SELECT...)

Tags: mysql

So, in my query I need to dump out results from different locations. Some of these results may need a "<" or ">" sign before them. Ultimately this query gets exported using INTO OUTFILE but that part works. What is happening is that when i try to concat the result from the gtlt value to the result value for a parameter always breaks... I've added the a,b,c, and x so you can see what is showing up where... I am pretty sure it has to to with the second where statement but I can't figure it out.

Anyway.... here is a striped down example of my code:

```
SELECT      
'VAR 1',
'VAR 2',
'VAR 3'
UNION   
(SELECT         
CONCAT(if(result.parameter = '10', result.gtlt,'a '),COALESCE(sum(if(result.parameter = '10', result.result, NULL)),'-')) as 'VAR 1',
CONCAT(if(result.parameter = '61', result.gtlt,'b '),COALESCE(sum(if(result.parameter = '61', result.result, NULL)),'-')) as 'VAR 2',
CONCAT(if(result.parameter = '78', result.gtlt,'c '),COALESCE(sum(if(result.parameter = '78', result.result, NULL)),'-')) as  'VAR 3'
FROM (  
    SELECT
        event.id,
        event.end_date,
        event_result.parameter,
        event_result.result,
        COALESCE(CAST(event_result.gtlt as CHAR), 'x') as gtlt,
        event.tag
    FROM event
    Inner Join event_result ON event_result.tag = event.tag
    Inner Join tblesdstations19 ON tblesdstations19.id = event.id
    WHERE (event.id =  '735' OR event.id =  '845' OR event.id =  '209') AND `event`.`end_date` >= '1998-01-13' AND `event`.`end_date` <= '2010-02-09') as result    
WHERE result.parameter = '10' OR result.parameter = '61' OR result.parameter = '78' group by result.id, result.end_date, result.tag
order by 
    result.id ASC, 
    result.end_date DESC )
```

Here is a sample of what is being returned:

```
VAR 1   VAR 2   VAR 3
x17.8   b 9.49  c -
x25.8   b 9.21  c -
x17.5   b 29    c 0.36
x16.6   b 9.6   c 0.52
x26.2   b 7.4   c 0.49
x24.3   b 7.9   c 0.34
x27.5   b 9.9   c -
 a -    x7.9    c -
 a -    x8.2    c -
 a -    x5.7    c -
x16.8   b 2.16  c -
x22.2   b 1.84  c -
x26.2   b - c -
x22.7   b 0.67  c -
x18.5   b 19    c 0.15
 x14    b 1.3   c 0.91
x19.5   b 12    c 0.38
 a -    x1.2    c -
x23.5   b 0.74  c 0.92
```

If I strip our VAR 1 and 2 selects and the where it works for VAR 3...

```
SELECT 'VAR 3'
UNION   
(SELECT         
CONCAT(if(result.parameter = '78', result.gtlt,'c '),COALESCE(sum(if(result.parameter = '78', result.result, NULL)),'-')) as  'VAR 3'
FROM (  
    SELECT
        event.id,
        event.end_date,
        event_result.parameter,
        event_result.result,
        COALESCE(CAST(event_result.gtlt as CHAR), 'x') as gtlt,
        event.tag
    FROM event
    Inner Join event_result ON event_result.tag = event.tag
    Inner Join tblesdstations19 ON tblesdstations19.id = event.id
    WHERE (event.id =  '735' OR event.id =  '845' OR event.id =  '209') AND `event`.`end_date` >= '1998-01-13' AND `event`.`end_date` <= '2010-02-09') as result    
WHERE result.parameter = '78' group by result.id, result.end_date, result.tag
order by 
    result.id ASC, 
    result.end_date DESC )
```

Gives me...

```
VAR 3
x0.36
>0.52
>0.49
>0.34
x0.15
>0.91
x0.38
x0.92
>0.48
```

EDIT: adding the parameter to the GROUPED BY list gives this result:

```
17.8     -   -
   -    9.49     -
25.8     -   -
   -    9.21     -
17.5     -   -
   -    29   -
   -     -  0.36
16.6     -   -
   -    9.6  -
   -     -  >0.52
26.2     -   -
etc...
```

Which shows the "<" ">" sypbols but doesn't give the values in rows like I need.

Comment: Only possibility I can see is that you are using GROUP BY without all the columns (no aggregate columns there anyway), one of which is the parameter column which is used in your coalesce. The value of that might well be indeterminate with multiple rows coming back (ie, first example) but in your second working example there will not be multiple values of this possible for a row.

Comment: Aren't those two outputs consistent: all the non-null "c" values from the first one show up in the second (except for the last "0.48", which I assume was simply not pasted)? Could you point to one particular value in the first output that is wrong?

Comment: x16.6   b 9.6   c 0.52 should be x16.6   x9.6   >0.52

Comment: @Kickstart see edit in post

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT!!!! instead of SUM I used GROUP_CONCAT and concatenated the result with the ">" or "<" in the sub result set

```
COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(if(result.parameter = '10', result.result, NULL)),'-') as 'VAR 1',
...
CONCAT(COALESCE(result.gtlt,''),' ',result.result) as result,
```